# to prove that a particular element is a central element

Tags: group-theory

If $x$ to $x^n$ is an automorphism of $G$. Show that for all $x\in G$, $x^{n-1}$ is a central element of $G$.

I am not really sure how to go about the proof so I am looking for some clue on how to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $x^{n-1}y^n = x^{-1}x^ny^n=x^{-1}(xy)^n= (yx)^nx^{-1}=y^nx^nx^{-1}=y^nx^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ g, x\in G$, we want to prove that $x^{n-1}g=gx^{n-1}$. Since $y$ to $y^n$ is an automorphism in $G$, we can assume without loss of generality, that there is $y\in G$ such that $y^n=g$.

Now, since $y$ to $y^n$ is an automorphism in $G$, 
$$ x^ny^n=(xy)^n \,\,\textrm{ and }\,\, y^nx^n=(yx)^n$$
So 
$$ x^{n-1}y^n=y(xy)^{n-1} \,\,\textrm{ and }\,\, y^nx^{n-1}=(yx)^{n-1}y$$
But $y(xy)^{n-1}$ and $(yx)^{n-1}y$ are exactly the same product of $x$ and $y$, so we have $ x^{n-1}y^n= y^nx^{n-1}$.